# Custom Language Definition for highlight.js

Tags: javascript, highlight.js

I want to define my own language in highlight.js, but I'm wondering how to do this. I found this guide

[Language definition guide](https://highlightjs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/language-guide.html)
with the following example. Does anybody know where I to put this configuration so that highlight.js use this configuration?

```
{
  case_insensitive: true, // language is case-insensitive
  keywords: 'for if while',
  contains: [
    {
      className: 'string',
      begin: '"', end: '"'
    },
    hljs.COMMENT(
      '/\\*', // begin
      '\\*/', // end
      {
        contains: [
          {
            className: 'doc', begin: '@\\w+'
          }
        ]
      }
    )
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Define a language with `hljs.registerLanguage`.

First argument: name of language.

Second argument: a function that returns an object

```js
hljs.registerLanguage('language name', function() {
  return {
    case_insensitive: true, // language is case-insensitive
    keywords: 'for if while',
    contains: [
      {
        className: 'string',
        begin: '"',
        end: '"'
      },
      hljs.COMMENT(
        '/\\*', // begin
        '\\*/', // end
        {
          contains: [{
            className: 'doc',
            begin: '@\\w+'
          }]
        }
      )
    ]
  }
})
```

With ES6 arrow function:

```js
hljs.register('language name', () => ({
    case_insensitive: true, // language is case-insensitive
    keywords: 'for if while',
    contains: [
      {
        className: 'string',
        begin: '"',
        end: '"'
      },
      hljs.COMMENT(
        '/\\*', // begin
        '\\*/', // end
        {
          contains: [{
            className: 'doc',
            begin: '@\\w+'
          }]
        }
      )
    ]
}))
```

Answer (score -2):

You can simply use the class attribute for specifying language in highlightjs.

For example if you are highlighting python code

```
<pre class="python">
<code>
print "Hello"
</code>
</pre>
```

Edit:
Create a file named `highlightcon.min.js` link it with your html file `<script src="highlightcon.min.js"></script>` And paste your configured objects into the highlightcon.min.js

If you want to define your own language that too with realtime syntax highting you can use ace editor as highlight js does not give the feature you are looking for...
In your `index.html` use

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Editor</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="views/style.css" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ace/1.4.12/ace.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- Elements -->
    <div id='container'>

        <div id="editor">
        </div>
      
        <iframe id='iframe' frameBorder="0">
        </iframe>
      </div>
      

    <!-- Javascript -->
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

`<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ace/1.4.12/ace.js">` is the ace editor cdn...
Then in your `script.js` file

```
function update()
{
    var idoc = document.getElementById('iframe').contentWindow.document;

    idoc.open();
    idoc.write(editor.getValue());
    idoc.close();
}

function setupEditor()
{
  window.editor = ace.edit("editor");
  editor.setTheme("ace/theme/monokai");
  editor.getSession().setMode("ace/mode/python");


  editor.getSession().on('change', function() {
    update();
  });

  editor.focus();
  
  
  editor.setOptions({
    fontSize: "16pt",
    showLineNumbers: true,
    showGutter: false,
    vScrollBarAlwaysVisible:true,
    enableBasicAutocompletion: true, enableLiveAutocompletion: true
  });

  editor.setShowPrintMargin(false);
  editor.setBehavioursEnabled(true);
}

setupEditor();
update();
const elementToObserve = document.querySelector("#editor");
```

Here, you define the language  `editor.getSession().setMode("ace/mode/python");` you can find it in the `script.js` below.
And you can use `editor.session.setMode("ace/mode/" + language)` just you need to specify the language like this before writing this command 
`var language = "python"`
This also gives real time syntax highlighting..

Comment: Sorry, but this doesn't awnser the question. I want to use my own language and I don't know wehere to put my language definition.

Comment: Hey @running_tomy, sorry to know that it didn't help. I have edited the answer and I think this would help, also sorry that highlightjs does not provide realtime syntax highlighting. Let me know if that helps.... –